# pvm says file not found when running an executable

Tags: pvm

I have Linux mint 17.1 64bit and installed pvm by apt , I also installed tcsh , my .cshrc file is this:

```
setenv PVM_ROOT /home/abd/pvm3
setenv PVM_ARCH `$PVM_ROOT/lib/pvmgetarch`    
set path=($path $PVM_ROOT/lib)
set path=($path $PVM_ROOT/lib/$PVM_ARCH)
```

The pvm3 folder is in home which has a lib folder and the lib folder has pvmgetarch folder.

I have a parent called ParentPerfectLot executable and a child called ChildPerfectLot, both are in ~/pvm3/lib/pvmgetarch

I go to pvm console and run:

```
spawn -> ParentPerfectLot
```

it says "No file found".

This may seem a beginner question but I haven't found much to help in the web, so what Am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, I just had to change .cshrc to this:

```
setenv PVM_ROOT /usr/lib/pvm3
setenv PVM_ARCH `$PVM_ROOT/lib/pvmgetarch`
setenv PVM_PATH `$HOME/pvm3/bin/$PVM_ARCH`
```

it seems PVM_PATH is the variable that must be given , Now I tried at first setting it to ~/pvm3/bin/LINUX64(my architecture) but it didn't work, it only worked when putting $HOME and $PVM_ARCH instead.

Ofcourse you can put whatever folder you want in PVM_PATH but PVM_ROOT and PVM_ARCH must always(in ubuntu and ubuntu-based OSes) be like above, other distros might have different configuration.